# I've changed email servers for client's domain email. Will Gmail delete its copies of the old messages?

Tags: gmail

I have a client whose domain email is set up to be checked from Gmail. I moved her web hosting account from netsol to gd and stupidly didn't check the implications that the move would have on her personal email (the email account was deleted). Fortunately, Gmail has copies of all of her email.

Now that I've set up her email on the new hosting package, I need to find out the best way to set up Gmail to check her domain email (which is the same email address as from her previous host) without deleting any of her messages from when that email was on the previous host.

In other words, if an email account is moved from server A to server B, how does Gmail treat all past emails?

Will its copies persist, or will they be deleted/archived?

Comment: Google will only delete your emails when the account is considered no longer active or you delete the emails yourself.  If all you did was move the actual email server, all you should have to do, is change the authentication information Gmail uses to download the emails.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, that's EXACTLY what I needed to know. Thanks! P.S. to the forum: I'm not sure why anyone would down vote my question, and the lack of constructive criticism over how to make my question better just makes me not want to use this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Google will only delete your emails when the account is considered no longer active or you delete the emails yourself.  If all you did was move the actual email server, all you should have to do, is change the authentication information Gmail uses to download the emails. -- [Ramhound](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53212/ive-changed-email-servers-for-clients-domain-email-will-gmail-delete-its-copi#comment42751_53212)

---

(Posted for the sake of having a proper answer here.)